# Exchange JSON data between 2 Android devices using WiFi-P2P

Tags: java, android, json, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I'm working on 2 Android applications witch have to exchange some sorts of data in JSON format using Bluetooth and WiFi P2P.

Bluetooth part went very well and everything works perfect.

The problems came at WiFi P2P implementation because I was not able to connect the sockets in order to exchange the data. The devices are well connected using the WiFi-P2P but the problems are at Socket programming level.

I don't get any error messages but the ServerSocket never receive the connection request. I have checked and both ServerSocket from the server app side and Socket from the client app side are bound to the same IP address: 192.168.49.1 port 8989.

Any help regarding what can be wrong in my code will be appreciated.

**This is the code on the app witch serve as a server:**

```
public class WiFiIO {

private static final String LOG = "UJUKE-CONTROLLER-WIFI-IO";

public static int SERVER_PORT = 8989;
public String IP = "";

private final Handler mHandler;

private AcceptThread mAcceptThread;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
private int mState;

// Constants that indicate the current connection state
public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

// Message types sent from the BluetoothChatService Handler
public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;

// Key names received from the BluetoothChatService Handler
public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
public static final String TOAST = "toast";


/**
 * Constructor. Prepares a new WiFi session.
 *
 * @param context The UI Activity Context
 * @param handler A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
 */
public WiFiIO(Context context, 
            Handler handler) {       
    mState = STATE_NONE;
    mHandler = handler;
}

/**
 * Set the current state of the chat connection
 *
 * @param state An integer defining the current connection state
 */
private synchronized void setState(int state) {
    Log.d(LOG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
    mState = state;

    // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
}

/**
 * Return the current connection state.
 */
public synchronized int getState() {
    return mState;
}

/**
 * Start the lisen service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
 * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume()
 */
public synchronized void start(String ip) {
    Log.d(LOG, "start");

   IP = ip;

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    setState(STATE_LISTEN);

    // Start the thread to listen on a ServerSocket
    if (mAcceptThread == null) {
        mAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
        mAcceptThread.start();
    }
}

/**
 * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a wi-fi connection
 *
 */
public synchronized void connected(Socket socket) {
    //Log.d(LOG, "connected to " + mConfig.deviceAddress);
    Log.d(LOG, "connected");

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device
    if (mAcceptThread != null) {
        mAcceptThread.cancel();
        mAcceptThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket, socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
    mConnectedThread.start();

    // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(DEVICE_NAME, "device");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}


/**
 * Stop all threads
 */
public synchronized void stop() {
    Log.d(LOG, "stop");

    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    if (mAcceptThread != null) {
        mAcceptThread.cancel();
        mAcceptThread = null;
    }
    setState(STATE_NONE);
}

/**
 * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
 *
 * @param out The bytes to write
 * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
 */
public void write(byte[] out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
        r = mConnectedThread;
    }
    // Perform the write unsynchronized
    r.write(out);
}

/**
 * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
 */
private void connectionLost() {     
    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
    WiFiIO.this.start(IP);
}

/**
 * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
 * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
 * (or until cancelled).
 */
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    // The local server socket
    private final ServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        ServerSocket tmp = null;

        // Create a new listening server socket
        try {
                tmp  = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);
                //tmp  = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT,50,InetAddress.getByName(IP)); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG, "Socket listen() failed", e);
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.d(LOG, "Socket BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
        setName("AcceptThread");

        Socket socket = null;

        // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
        while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception                    
                Log.e(LOG, "Socket server bonded to ip" + mmServerSocket.getInetAddress().toString());
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG, "Socket Type  accept() failed", e);
                //break;
            }

            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (WiFiIO.this) {
                    switch (mState) {
                        case STATE_LISTEN:
                        case STATE_CONNECTING:
                            // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                            connected(socket);
                            break;
                        case STATE_NONE:
                        case STATE_CONNECTED:
                            // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.e(LOG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Log.i(LOG, "END mAcceptThread, socket Type");

    }

    public void cancel() {
        Log.d(LOG, "Socket Type cancel " + this);
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG, "Socket Type close() of server failed", e);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
 * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
 */
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final Socket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(Socket socket, SocketAddress address) {
        Log.d(LOG, "create ConnectedThread: ");
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(LOG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                int timeout = 0;
                int maxTimeout = 32; // leads to a timeout of 2 seconds
                int available = 0;

                while((available = mmInStream.available()) == 0 && timeout < maxTimeout) {
                    timeout++;
                    // throws interrupted exception
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(250);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                // Read from the InputStream
                buffer = new byte[available];
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                WiFiIO.this.start(IP);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write to the connected OutStream.
     *
     * @param buffer The bytes to write
     */
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            //mmOutStream.write(buffer);
            mmOutStream.write(buffer,0,buffer.length);
            mmOutStream.flush();
            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmOutStream.close();
            mmInStream.close();
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

**This is the code on the app witch serve as a client:**

```
public class WiFiIO {

private static final String LOG = "UJUKE-CONTROLLER-WIFI-IO";

public static int SERVER_PORT = 8989;

private final Handler mHandler;

private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
private int mState;

// Constants that indicate the current connection state
public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

// Message types sent from the BluetoothChatService Handler
public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;

// Key names received from the BluetoothChatService Handler
public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
public static final String TOAST = "toast";

/**
 * Constructor. Prepares a new WiFi session.
 *
 * @param context The UI Activity Context
 * @param handler A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
 */
public WiFiIO(Handler handler) {
    mState = STATE_NONE;
    mHandler = handler;
}

/**
 * Set the current state of the chat connection
 *
 * @param state An integer defining the current connection state
 */
private synchronized void setState(int state) {
    Log.d(LOG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
    mState = state;

    // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
}

/**
 * Return the current connection state.
 */
public synchronized int getState() {
    return mState;
}

/**
 * Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
 *
 * @param device The IP address to connect
 */
public synchronized void connect(String ip) {
    Log.d(LOG, "connect to: " + ip);

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to connect with the given device
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(ip);
    mConnectThread.start();
    setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
}

/**
 * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a WiFi connection
 *
 * @param socket The Socket on which the connection was made
 */
public synchronized void connected(Socket socket) {
    Log.d(LOG, "connected, Socket Type");

    // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
    mConnectedThread.start();

    // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(DEVICE_NAME, socket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString());
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
}

/**
 * Stop all threads
 */
public synchronized void stop() {
    Log.d(LOG, "stop");

    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    setState(STATE_NONE);
}

/**
 * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
 *
 * @param out The bytes to write
 * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
 */
public void write(byte[] out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
        r = mConnectedThread;
    }
    // Perform the write unsynchronized
    r.write(out);
}

/**
 * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
 */
private void connectionFailed() {
    setState(STATE_NONE);
    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}

/**
 * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
 */
private void connectionLost() {
    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}

/**
 * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
 * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
 * succeeds or fails.
 */
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final Socket mmSocket;
    private final String mmIP;

    public ConnectThread(String ip) {
        Socket tmp = null;

        // Get a Socket for a connection with the
        // given ip
        //try {
                tmp = new Socket();
        //} catch (IOException e) {
          //  Log.e(LOG, "Socket Type: create() failed", e);
        //}
        mmSocket = tmp;
        mmIP = ip;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(LOG, "BEGIN mConnectThread ");
        setName("ConnectThread");

        // Make a connection to the ServerSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            while(mmSocket.isConnected() == false){
                try{
                    mmSocket.bind(null);
                    mmSocket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(mmIP, SERVER_PORT)),0);
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG, "unable to connect to server socket", e);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e(LOG, "unable to close()  socket during connection failure", e2);
            }
            connectionFailed();
            return;
        }

        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (WiFiIO.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(mmSocket);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
 * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
 */
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final Socket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(Socket socket) {
        Log.d(LOG, "create ConnectedThread");
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the Socket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        if(mmOutStream != null){
            String s = "start";
            write(s.getBytes());
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(LOG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                int timeout = 0;
                int maxTimeout = 32; // leads to a timeout of 2 seconds
                int available = 0;

                while((available = mmInStream.available()) == 0 && timeout < maxTimeout) {
                    timeout++;
                    // throws interrupted exception
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(250);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                // Read from the InputStream
                buffer = new byte[available];
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write to the connected OutStream.
     *
     * @param buffer The bytes to write
     */
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);
            mmOutStream.flush();
            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmOutStream.close();
            mmInStream.close();
            mmSocket.close();                
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Wow I'm so late to the party ... Anyways did you finally achieve your goal ? ( Do you even remember ? )